# Multiple update from C# 3.0

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a folder that contains more than 100 .txt files. These files contain huge amount of data that needs to be orchestrated and updated in the SQL Server table. Each text file line will have only two columns that interests me and based upon the 1st column data (which is a PK in the SQL Server Table) I want to update the 2nd column data in the DB table.

Please suggest the best way to do it in C# 3.0

Presently I am using a StringBuilder and appending the Update query.

Comment: This is only for update, not inserts?

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should use [Bulk Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to import the data to the sql server and then you write stored procedure. Building the query and then running will make the whole process slow.

Comment: Not exactly the C# approach they asked for.

Comment: Using the same through Database will complex the things for me as DB server do not have the privileges to read those files.